# react-native fabric Fatal Exception

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, crashlytics

We released our application a few weeks ago. It's a really big app, so I can't really post the whole code.

However, we're getting an error in `Fabric.io` and we don't know the source. Has anyone ever seen an error like this?

```
#9. Crashed: com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.exception
0  Aktionis.ch                    0xbf37b CLSProcessRecordAllThreads (CLSProcess.c:376)
1  Aktionis.ch                    0xbf37b CLSProcessRecordAllThreads (CLSProcess.c:376)
2  Aktionis.ch                    0xbf595 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads (CLSProcess.c:403)
3  Aktionis.ch                    0xb3d5d CLSHandler (CLSHandler.m:26)
4  Aktionis.ch                    0xbe0d7 __CLSExceptionRecord_block_invoke (CLSException.mm:199)
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x39eaa81f _dispatch_client_callout + 22
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x39ebcdd7 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 26
7  Aktionis.ch                    0xbdadf CLSExceptionRecord (CLSException.mm:206)
8  Aktionis.ch                    0xbd90d CLSExceptionRecordNSException (CLSException.mm:101)
9  Aktionis.ch                    0xbd47b CLSTerminateHandler() (CLSException.mm:253)
10 libc++abi.dylib                0x3927b1c7 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 78
11 libc++abi.dylib                0x3927aa1d __cxxabiv1::exception_cleanup_func(_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Exception*) + 114
12 libobjc.A.dylib                0x399c2da3 objc_exception_throw + 250
13 Aktionis.ch                    0x275159 -[RCTBatchedBridge _handleRequestNumber:moduleID:methodID:params:] (RCTBatchedBridge.m:1003)
14 Aktionis.ch                    0x274a9f __33-[RCTBatchedBridge handleBuffer:]_block_invoke.329 (RCTBatchedBridge.m:916)
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x39eaa833 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x39eaaded _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$up + 444
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x39eab297 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$up + 38
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x39ebd88d _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 76
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x39ebdb21 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 56
20 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39fecbd3 _pthread_wqthread + 298
21 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39feca98 start_wqthread + 8

--

Fatal Exception: RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'n._currentElement')
0  CoreFoundation                 0x2f211f83 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x399c2ccf objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x2f211ec5 -[NSException initWithCoder:]
3  Aktionis.ch                    0x255e39 RCTFatal (RCTAssert.m:137)
4  Aktionis.ch                    0x2516d5 -[RCTExceptionsManager reportFatalException:stack:exceptionId:] (RCTExceptionsManager.m:64)
5  CoreFoundation                 0x2f215534 __invoking___
6  CoreFoundation                 0x2f16008b -[NSInvocation invoke]
7  CoreFoundation                 0x2f163823 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:]
8  Aktionis.ch                    0x2544a3 -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] (RCTModuleMethod.m:500)
9  Aktionis.ch                    0x274fd1 -[RCTBatchedBridge _handleRequestNumber:moduleID:methodID:params:] (RCTBatchedBridge.m:988)
10 Aktionis.ch                    0x274a9f __33-[RCTBatchedBridge handleBuffer:]_block_invoke.329 (RCTBatchedBridge.m:916)
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x39eaa833 _dispatch_call_block_and_release
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x39eaaded _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$up
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x39eab297 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$up
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x39ebd88d _dispatch_root_queue_drain
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x39ebdb21 _dispatch_worker_thread2
16 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39fecbd3 _pthread_wqthread
17 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39feca98 start_wqthread

#0. com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x39f72a58 mach_msg_trap + 20
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x39f72859 mach_msg + 48
2  CoreFoundation                 0x2f1dc84b __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 154
3  CoreFoundation                 0x2f1dafb7 __CFRunLoopRun + 854
4  CoreFoundation                 0x2f145ebf CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
5  CoreFoundation                 0x2f145ca3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
6  GraphicsServices               0x3404b663 GSEventRunModal + 138
7  UIKit                          0x31a9214d UIApplicationMain + 1136
8  Aktionis.ch                    0x1ca9d main (main.m:16)
9  libdyld.dylib                  0x39ecfab7 start + 2

#1. com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x39f72808 kevent64 + 24
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x39ebeded _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 232
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x39eadf73 _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$up + 38

#2. WebThread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x39f72a58 mach_msg_trap + 20
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x39f72859 mach_msg + 48
2  CoreFoundation                 0x2f1dc84b __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 154
3  CoreFoundation                 0x2f1daf71 __CFRunLoopRun + 784
4  CoreFoundation                 0x2f145ebf CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
5  CoreFoundation                 0x2f145ca3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
6  WebCore                        0x373dd1ab RunWebThread(void*) + 418
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39fee919 _pthread_body + 140
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39fee88b _pthread_start + 102
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39fecaa4 thread_start + 8

#3. com.apple.root.default-priority
0  libsystem_platform.dylib       0x39fe6d62 _platform_memmove$VARIANT$CortexA8 + 777
1  ImageIO                        0x2ff5e16f copyImageBlockSetPNG + 2426
2  ImageIO                        0x2ff5d27f ImageProviderCopyImageBlockSetCallback + 542
3  CoreGraphics                   0x2f29932d CGImageProviderCopyImageBlockSetWithOptions + 136
4  CoreGraphics                   0x2f2bbf23 CGImageProviderCopyImageBlockSet + 26
5  CoreGraphics                   0x2f298ffb img_blocks_create + 406
6  CoreGraphics                   0x2f2bbef3 img_blocks_extent + 62
7  CoreGraphics                   0x2f2bbead img_interpolate_extent + 108
8  CoreGraphics                   0x2f28d041 img_data_lock + 4408
9  CoreGraphics                   0x2f28b705 CGSImageDataLock + 88
10 libRIP.A.dylib                 0x2f5d7e67 ripc_AcquireImage
11 libRIP.A.dylib                 0x2f5d720d ripc_DrawImage
12 CoreGraphics                   0x2f28b61b CGContextDelegateDrawImage + 50
13 CoreGraphics                   0x2f28b4b1 CGContextDrawImage + 284
14 ImageIO                        0x2ff7e2f5 CGImageCreateCopyWithParametersNew + 1736
15 ImageIO                        0x2ff7dad5 CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex + 2380
16 Aktionis.ch                    0x2a934b RCTDecodeImageWithData (RCTImageUtils.m:260)
17 Aktionis.ch                    0x2a54f3 __80-[RCTImageLoader decodeImageData:size:scale:clipped:resizeMode:completionBlock:]_block_invoke_4 (RCTImageLoader.m:587)
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x39eaa833 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x39ebd921 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 224
20 libdispatch.dylib              0x39ebdb21 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 56
21 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39fecbd3 _pthread_wqthread + 298
22 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39feca98 start_wqthread + 8

#4. JavaScriptCore::BlockFree
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x39f84f2c __psynch_cvwait + 24
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39fedf27 _pthread_cond_wait + 522
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39feed65 pthread_cond_wait + 40
3  JavaScriptCore                 0x30173c91 JSC::BlockAllocator::blockFreeingThreadMain() + 208
4  JavaScriptCore                 0x301712e3 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 14
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39fee919 _pthread_body + 140
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39fee88b _pthread_start + 102
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39fecaa4 thread_start + 8

#5. com.facebook.react.JavaScript
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x39f72a58 mach_msg_trap + 20
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x39f72859 mach_msg + 48
2  CoreFoundation                 0x2f1dc84b __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 154
3  CoreFoundation                 0x2f1daf71 __CFRunLoopRun + 784
4  CoreFoundation                 0x2f145ebf CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
5  CoreFoundation                 0x2f145ca3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
6  Aktionis.ch                    0x26c6f1 +[RCTJSCExecutor runRunLoopThread] (RCTJSCExecutor.mm:259)
7  Foundation                     0x2fbfba5f __NSThread__main__ + 1062
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39fee919 _pthread_body + 140
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39fee88b _pthread_start + 102
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39fecaa4 thread_start + 8

#6. JavaScriptCore::BlockFree
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x39f84f2c __psynch_cvwait + 24
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39fedf27 _pthread_cond_wait + 522
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39feeda5 pthread_cond_timedwait + 44
3  JavaScriptCore                 0x30173ded WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 108
4  JavaScriptCore                 0x30173c1d JSC::BlockAllocator::blockFreeingThreadMain() + 92
5  JavaScriptCore                 0x301712e3 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 14
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39fee919 _pthread_body + 140
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39fee88b _pthread_start + 102
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39fecaa4 thread_start + 8

#7. com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.MachExceptionServer
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x39f72a58 mach_msg_trap + 20
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x39f72859 mach_msg + 48
2  Aktionis.ch                    0xaf7d3 CLSMachExceptionServer (CLSMachException.c:179)
3  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39fee919 _pthread_body + 140
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39fee88b _pthread_start + 102
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39fecaa4 thread_start + 8

#8. com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x39f72a58 mach_msg_trap + 20
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x39f72859 mach_msg + 48
2  CoreFoundation                 0x2f1dc84b __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 154
3  CoreFoundation                 0x2f1daf71 __CFRunLoopRun + 784
4  CoreFoundation                 0x2f145ebf CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
5  CoreFoundation                 0x2f145ca3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
6  Foundation                     0x2fb86087 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 318
7  Foundation                     0x2fbfba5f __NSThread__main__ + 1062
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39fee919 _pthread_body + 140
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39fee88b _pthread_start + 102
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39fecaa4 thread_start + 8

#9. Crashed: com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.exception
0  Aktionis.ch                    0xbf37b CLSProcessRecordAllThreads (CLSProcess.c:376)
1  Aktionis.ch                    0xbf37b CLSProcessRecordAllThreads (CLSProcess.c:376)
2  Aktionis.ch                    0xbf595 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads (CLSProcess.c:403)
3  Aktionis.ch                    0xb3d5d CLSHandler (CLSHandler.m:26)
4  Aktionis.ch                    0xbe0d7 __CLSExceptionRecord_block_invoke (CLSException.mm:199)
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x39eaa81f _dispatch_client_callout + 22
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x39ebcdd7 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 26
7  Aktionis.ch                    0xbdadf CLSExceptionRecord (CLSException.mm:206)
8  Aktionis.ch                    0xbd90d CLSExceptionRecordNSException (CLSException.mm:101)
9  Aktionis.ch                    0xbd47b CLSTerminateHandler() (CLSException.mm:253)
10 libc++abi.dylib                0x3927b1c7 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 78
11 libc++abi.dylib                0x3927aa1d __cxxabiv1::exception_cleanup_func(_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Exception*) + 114
12 libobjc.A.dylib                0x399c2da3 objc_exception_throw + 250
13 Aktionis.ch                    0x275159 -[RCTBatchedBridge _handleRequestNumber:moduleID:methodID:params:] (RCTBatchedBridge.m:1003)
14 Aktionis.ch                    0x274a9f __33-[RCTBatchedBridge handleBuffer:]_block_invoke.329 (RCTBatchedBridge.m:916)
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x39eaa833 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x39eaaded _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$up + 444
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x39eab297 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$up + 38
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x39ebd88d _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 76
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x39ebdb21 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 56
20 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39fecbd3 _pthread_wqthread + 298
21 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39feca98 start_wqthread + 8

#10. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x39f72a58 mach_msg_trap + 20
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x39f72859 mach_msg + 48
2  CoreFoundation                 0x2f1dc84b __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 154
3  CoreFoundation                 0x2f1daf71 __CFRunLoopRun + 784
4  CoreFoundation                 0x2f145ebf CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
5  CoreFoundation                 0x2f145ca3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
6  libAVFAudio.dylib              0x2e1a5451 GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 128
7  libAVFAudio.dylib              0x2e1997bf CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 178
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39fee919 _pthread_body + 140
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39fee88b _pthread_start + 102
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39fecaa4 thread_start + 8

#11. com.apple.CFSocket.private
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x39f85434 __select + 20
1  CoreFoundation                 0x2f1e070d __CFSocketManager + 484
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39fee919 _pthread_body + 140
3  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39fee88b _pthread_start + 102
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39fecaa4 thread_start + 8

#12. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x39f74630 fsync + 8
1  libsqlite3.dylib               0x39ca4491 (null) + 29932
2  libsqlite3.dylib               0x39ca9e6d (null) + 1600
3  libsqlite3.dylib               0x39ca42a7 (null) + 29442
4  libsqlite3.dylib               0x39c99d69 (null) + 9692
5  libsqlite3.dylib               0x39c7b16d (null) + 2048
6  libsqlite3.dylib               0x39c967fb (null) + 40674
7  libsqlite3.dylib               0x39c8cab1 sqlite3_step + 408
8  Aktionis.ch                    0x4ff77 -[GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore upsertPropertyRecord:] (GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore.m:235)
9  Aktionis.ch                    0x4fa33 -[GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore nextHitNumberForTrackingId:clientId:] (GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore.m:168)
10 Aktionis.ch                    0x49e67 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher queueDispatch:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:692)
11 Aktionis.ch                    0x49c9b -[GAIBatchingDispatcher queueModel:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:670)
12 Foundation                     0x2fbfbc73 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 386
13 CoreFoundation                 0x2f1dd20b __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
14 CoreFoundation                 0x2f1dc6db __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 206
15 CoreFoundation                 0x2f1daecf __CFRunLoopRun + 622
16 CoreFoundation                 0x2f145ebf CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
17 CoreFoundation                 0x2f145ca3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
18 Foundation                     0x2fb391eb -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 254
19 Foundation                     0x2fb8a0a1 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 80
20 Aktionis.ch                    0x38d4d +[GAI threadMain:] (GAI.m:229)
21 Foundation                     0x2fbfba5f __NSThread__main__ + 1062
22 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39fee919 _pthread_body + 140
23 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39fee88b _pthread_start + 102
24 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39fecaa4 thread_start + 8

#13. WebCore: CFNetwork Loader
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x39f72a58 mach_msg_trap + 20
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x39f72859 mach_msg + 48
2  CoreFoundation                 0x2f1dc84b __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 154
3  CoreFoundation                 0x2f1daf71 __CFRunLoopRun + 784
4  CoreFoundation                 0x2f145ebf CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
5  CoreFoundation                 0x2f145ca3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
6  WebCore                        0x37425bb7 WebCore::runLoaderThread(void*) + 254
7  JavaScriptCore                 0x301712e3 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 14
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39fee919 _pthread_body + 140
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39fee88b _pthread_start + 102
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39fecaa4 thread_start + 8

#14. WebCore: LocalStorage
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x39f84f2c __psynch_cvwait + 24
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39fedf27 _pthread_cond_wait + 522
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39feed65 pthread_cond_wait + 40
3  JavaScriptCore                 0x30173dbf WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 62
4  WebCore                        0x375100a9 WTF::PassOwnPtr<WTF::Function<void ()> > WTF::MessageQueue<WTF::Function<void ()> >::waitForMessageFilteredWithTimeout<bool (WTF::Function<void ()>*)>(WTF::MessageQueueWaitResult&, bool (&)(WTF::Function<void ()>*), double) + 108
5  WebCore                        0x3751002f WebCore::StorageThread::threadEntryPoint() + 166
6  JavaScriptCore                 0x301712e3 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 14
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39fee919 _pthread_body + 140
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39fee88b _pthread_start + 102
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39fecaa4 thread_start + 8

#15. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x39f85c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39fecbdf _pthread_wqthread + 310
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39feca98 start_wqthread + 8

#16. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x39f85c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39fecbdf _pthread_wqthread + 310
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x39feca98 start_wqthread + 8
```

thanks for any help

Comment: Could you try to post a subset of your code, to reproduce the problem?

Comment: well as I mentioned it's a really huge application. Maybe if anyone can give me some hints when this issue could happen I can post the code there... I'm not really having a plan where to start searching

Comment: It's generally advisable to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without knowing how to reproduce your problem, it's far less likely you'll get an answer.